# Rspec: before each on js:true specs only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

For all my js:true feature specs
e.g.

```
scenario "test something", js: true do
end
```

I want to say run some arbitrary code 
e.g

```
visit signin_path
```

I know I could do within spec_helper.rb

```
config.before(:each) do
 visit signin_path
end
```

But I only want to run this for specs with **js:true**

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, just specify a separate before(:each, js: true) block in your `spec_helper.rb`

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, js: true)  do
    visit signin_path
  end
end
```